# How to return last ocurrence of a name in column A if the content in column B is not empty

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying so hard to develop a function that returns the last ocurrence of a name in column A if the content in column B is not empty. I illustrated the behavior of this in the image bellow:

[image]

The formula should:

- Ignore empty spaces in column A
- No need for changes if rows are added

I couldn't go further than that:

```
=INDEX(A3:B,SMALL(IF(A3:A=D2,ROW(A3:A)-ROW(A3)+1,ROW(INDIRECT("A"&COUNTA($A:$A)))+1),COUNTIF(A3:A,D2)),2)
```

Any help?

Thanks

Link to the sheet (GOOGLE SHEETS) in image: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tYmq4H4i9Y3LJnOOkT8XArNzEWnkhpEk1yDiBjvctRI/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SORTN(QUERY(SORT({A3:B\ ROW(A3:A)}; 3; 0); 
 "where Col2 is not null"; 0); 9^9; 2; 1; 1); 9^9; 2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With data like:

[image]

We want to retrieve the **last** non-blank value in column **B** associated with `Matthew`

In **C1** enter `Matthew` and in **D1** enter:

```
=INDEX(B:B,LOOKUP(2,1/((A:A=C1)*(B:B<>"")),ROW(A:A)))
```

[image]

*(works the same way in Excel)*